# How to only enable servo when the input from sensors is changed in Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, iot, microcontroller, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I tried to write an Arduino Uno program for automatic watering system. I want to make the servo turned off after 5 second delay and stay disabled until the input from the sensors changed. But my servo keeps reactivated in each loop iteration. It will only disabled when the condition is not met anymore. How do i fix this?

Specification:

1. Two potentiometers (these potentiometers will be replaced with BH1170 and Soil Moisture sensor, but since Wokwi does not have these sensors, I use potentiometers as replacement).
2. Arduino Uno R3
3. Ultrasonic Sensors for water level monitoring
4. LCD I2C 16x2 Display
5. Servo (I use this as replacement for mini water pump)
6. Pienzo buzzer (this should be on when water level is too low (below 80))

Here's my code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#define SOIL_SENSOR A0
#define ULTRASONIC_TRIG 13
#define ULTRASONIC_ECHO A1
#define POTENTIOMETER A2
#define SERVO_PIN 3
#define PIEZO_PIN 9

#define SERVO_DURATION 5000

#define ULTRASONIC_THRESHOLD 80
#define SOIL_THRESHOLD 500
#define POTENTIOMETER_THRESHOLD 500

int soilValue = 0;
int ultrasonicValue = 0;
int potentiometerValue = 0;
int flag = 0;

int new_soilValue = 0;
int new_ultrasonicValue = 0;
int new_potentiometerValue 0;

Servo servo;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

void setup() {
  pinMode(PIEZO_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ULTRASONIC_TRIG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ULTRASONIC_ECHO, INPUT);
  pinMode(SOIL_SENSOR, INPUT);
  pinMode(POTENTIOMETER, INPUT);
  
  servo.attach(SERVO_PIN);
  
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Soil:");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Light:");
}

void loop() {

  new_soilValue = analogRead(SOIL_SENSOR);
  new_ultrasonicValue = getUltrasonicDistance();
  new_potentiometerValue = analogRead(POTENTIOMETER);
  
  lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
  lcd.print(new_soilValue);
  lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
  lcd.print(new_potentiometerValue);

  if (new_soilValue != soilValue || new_potentiometerValue != potentiometerValue || new_ultrasonicValue != ultrasonicValue) {
    flag = 1;
    soilValue = new_soilValue;
    potentiometerValue = new_potentiometerValue;
    ultrasonicValue = new_ultrasonicValue;

    if (flag == 1) {
      if(soilValue < SOIL_THRESHOLD && potentiometerValue > POTENTIOMETER_THRESHOLD && ultrasonicValue < ULTRASONIC_THRESHOLD) {
        servo.write(180);
        delay(SERVO_DURATION);
        servo.write(0);
      } else if (new_ultrasonicValue > ULTRASONIC_THRESHOLD) {
        digitalWrite(PIEZO_PIN, HIGH);
        tone(9, 1000);
        delay(500);
        noTone(9);
        delay(500);
      } 
      flag = 0;
    }
  }
  servo.write(0);
}

int getUltrasonicDistance() {
  digitalWrite(ULTRASONIC_TRIG, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(ULTRASONIC_TRIG, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(ULTRASONIC_TRIG, LOW);
  
  int duration = pulseIn(ULTRASONIC_ECHO, HIGH);
  int distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
  return distance;
}
```

And here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It seems as if this is not an issue of the servo, but of your conditions. Debug your program and watch the values in the boolean expressions of your `if`s. You might find that the sampled values "jitter" and you need to filter this.

Comment: `until the input from the sensors changed` which sensor input should trigger the Servo rotation? Please check the condition `if(soilValue < SOIL_THRESHOLD && potentiometerValue > POTENTIOMETER_THRESHOLD && ultrasonicValue < ULTRASONIC_THRESHOLD)`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was the ultrasonic sensor that cause the problem. It keeps changing its value by itself even though I didn't change it. Removing the ultrasonic value from if statement solved it. Thank you everyone.

```
if (newSoilValue != soilValue || newPotentiometerValue != potentiometerValue) {
    soilValue = newSoilValue;
    potentiometerValue = newPotentiometerValue;
    ultrasonicValue = newUltrasonicValue;
    sensorValuesChanged = true;
  } else {
    sensorValuesChanged = false;
  }
```